# Rails 3 - Dashboard Monitoring / Analytics Problem

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, analytics, dashboard

I have the following associations:

```
Outlet => has_many :problems
User => has_many :problems
Checkin => belongs_to :outlet, belongs_to :user
```

When creating a **New Checkin**, the User_id is set automatically from the ID of the current user, and the Outlet is selected from a drop down box (which uses the outlet_id):

```
<%= f.collection_select :outlet_id, Outlet.all, :id, :name %>
```

**Each day, each outlet needs to be checked in to once.**

Im trying to get two pages:

1. One to display all the Outlets that **have not been** checked into today.
2. One to display all the Outlets that **have** been checked into today.

For the second page I was thinking I could possibly do:

```
Checkin.where('created_at = Date.today')
```

But I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it? or even if it would work?
I have no clue as to how I would display the Outlets which have NOT been checked into - as I'm not sure how I would get the Outlet list, and check for each one if a checkin had been made today.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I was considering setting it up so that everyday a checkin is created for each outlet. But one of the fields (i.e.:arrived [which could be a boolean]) could be unchecked. And then when a checkin is made, it could just tick the checkbox.

But then this has the downside of creating lots of records unncesccessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure there's a great Rails way of doing this, but here's my best try:

```
# All outlet ids into an array
outlets = Outlets.all
outlet_ids = outlets.map(&:id)
# All the outlet ids of the checkins
checked_in = Checkins.where('created_at = Date.today')
checked_in_outlet_ids = checked_in.map(&:outlet_id)
# All outlet ids not in checkins
not_checked_in = outlet_ids - checked_in_outlet_ids
```

So first we grab all the ids of all possible outlets. Then we query to find the outlets that were checked in today. We use a Proc trick to get an array of just the ids on both queries. We then use the difference operator on both arrays to return a new array called `not_checked_in`. This array will contain all the ids that aren't checked in today.